# Saving and restoring highlighting patterns

Tags: syntax-highlighting, keyboard-macros

I have some log files that I spend a lot of time reading, and I find myself doing the same series of commands to get useful highlighting each time I open a new log. Typically some combination of `M-x highlight-phrase` and `M-x highlight-lines-matching-regexp`.

What is the best way to consolidate this down to a single command (macro perhaps?) Or better yet, have the highlighting applied whenever I open a file matching a specific name pattern?

Comment: Clarification: do you mean you want to highlight particular phrases in a new log, make your highlighting *persist* between multiple sessions with the same log, or both?  The question body suggests the former, but the question header implies you want to do both.

Comment: Both, whenever I open one of my log files, regardless if I've opened it previously, I'd like to be able to easily apply the same highlighting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using a keyboard macro is a valid option, as is defining a custom command. The main advantage of using a keyboard macro is that you don't have to know any Elisp to create it. On the other hand, custom commands are easier to modify later on. I'm going to outline both solutions; feel free to pick the one you're most comfortable with.

#### Solution 1: Keyboard macro

To **record** the macro:

1. Press <kbd>F3</kbd> in a buffer showing a log file to start recording the macro.
2. Execute commands for highlighting lines and phrases as you normally would.
3. When you're done, press <kbd>F4</kbd> to stop recording.

To **persist** the macro:

1. Name the macro by doing

   <kbd>M-x</kbd> `name-last-kbd-macro` <kbd>RET</kbd> `highlight-log-file` <kbd>RET</kbd>
2. Find your init-file, move point to a place where you would like to insert the macro, and do

   <kbd>M-x</kbd> `insert-kbd-macro` <kbd>RET</kbd> `highlight-log-file` <kbd>RET</kbd>
3. **Optional**: Bind the macro to a key via

   ```
   (global-set-key (kbd "C-c h") 'highlight-log-file)
   ```
4. Save your init-file.

#### Solution 2: Custom command

Let's say you want to highlight

- all occurrences of `foo`
- all lines containing the phrase `bar`

in your log files. To achieve this you can define the following command:

```el
(defun highlight-log-file ()
  (interactive)
  (highlight-phrase "foo")
  (highlight-lines-matching-regexp "bar"))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c h") 'highlight-log-file)
```

If you need to highlight additional phrases/lines, just add more calls to `highlight-phrase` and `highlight-lines-matching-regexp` to the body of the command.

Note also that you can instruct Emacs to highlight phrases/lines using a specific color by passing a second argument to the `highlight-*` functions:

```
(highlight-phrase "bar" 'hi-green)
```

#### Automated highlighting

After defining `highlight-log-file` using one of the methods shown above you can instruct Emacs to automatically highlight relevant phrases/lines in `.log` files as follows:

```el
(defun apply-highlighting ()
  (when (string= (file-name-extension (buffer-file-name)) "log")
    (highlight-log-file)))

(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'apply-highlighting)
```

Comment: I went for solution #2, as it seems a little more elegant, and a bit easier to tweak

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest using a hook?

`(add-hook 'find-file-hook (lambda () (highlight-regexp "\\<ImportantWord\\>")))`

You could also throw an eye to [FixmeMode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FixmeMode)

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility to save highlighting regexps, but to the buffer at point so not sure it is useful to put in a log file. Anyway, it is the function `hi-lock-write-interactive-patterns`, bound to `C-x w b` (see the Edit menu).